# Files are not deleted from incoming queue folder

Tags: web8.5, deployer

We are migrating to SDL WEB 8.5, publication works fine, but I've realized the incoming queue folder has a lot of files with `.lock` extension. So I've reviewed the log and I found this error:

> ERROR FSDeployerQueue - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Failed to delete serialized command 'D:\SDL\live\service_folder\queue\incoming\ContentQueue\tcm_0-2479122-66560.Content.json'

if I go to that folder, I find this file `tcm_0-2479122-66560.Content.lock`

I've cleaned the folder and sent to publish again, and I was able to confirm, all files are renamed to `.lock` and remains into the folder instead of being deleted.

Any idea why this is happening? thank you !!

Comment: The most likely reason is that the service is running as a user who does not have permission to delete files in that folder. Have you checked the file system permissions?

Comment: For others stumbling across this - I've also seen something similar when an anti-virus checker was scanning the incoming folder making _some_ deletions impossible; this was more difficult to track as it seemed random given it wasn't all files (or the same published items each time)

Answer (score 2):

I've re-installed deployer service, after that, files are deleted from the folder.
I don't have the explanation of what was wrong, but at least, I have the solution to this problem.

thanks
Carolina